# importing a module from input

Tags: input, python-3.x, import

Forgive a noob. This may be beyond me.
I currently import variables from a module via

```
from a import *
```

What I aim to do is import the file as per the input string.

```
mod=str(input("Select a module: "))
from str(mod) import *
```

This is what I tried. Clearly wrong. I would like the code to ask for an input, which would be the name of a specific module, then import what the user inputs. 
Sorry I can provide any more code, the nature of the question prevents me from being capable of showing what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `__import__()`:

```
>>> d = __import__("datetime")
>>> d
<module 'datetime' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\datetime.py'>
```

For a more sophisticated importing I suggest using [importlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html).

EDIT1 to make it more clear:

```
>>> mymodule = __import__(input("Which module you want?" ))
>>> mymodule.var1
```

If you want `var1` instead of `mymodule.var1`, I would make aliases to the global namespace. However, I wouldn't do that since I do not see any sense in that.